# How to check if a module is imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import

I use numpy and scipy for data analysis. I want to write a code inside a function that I define so that when the function is called it check if, for example, numpy is imported and if it is not imported, then it should import it.

How can I check if any module such as numpy imported?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) in the `sys` module for this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import numpy
>>> 'numpy' in sys.modules
True
```

So your function could be:

```
def is_imported(module):
    return module in sys.modules
```

From the comments, you also wanted to return `True` if you'd used

```
from skimage.morphology import watershed
```

You can check if a function is in the current namespace by using [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)

```
>>> 'watershed' in dir()
False
>>> from skimage.morphology import watershed
>>> 'watershed' in dir()
True
```

To import a module using a string, you can use [`importlib.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module):

```
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.import_module('numpy')
```

Comment: Thanks, If for example I only import one specific functionality I doe snot work. For example I import watershed from skimage as:
`from skimage.morphology import watershed` then doing:
'watershed' in sys.modules returns false. Is there a fix to this situation too?

Answer (score 1):

The `import` statement is idempotent - it already checks whether the module has been loaded. Using `import module` in your function already does what you want:

```
def my_func():
    import numpy  # load numpy if not available
    # use numpy
```

This works for all kinds of imports, including submodules, relative imports and aliasing of members.

```
 def my_other_func():
     # load skimage, skimage.morphology, and
     # skimage.morphology.watershed if they are unimported modules
     from skimage.morphology import watershed
```

> During import, the module name is looked up in `sys.modules` and if present, the associated value is the module satisfying the import, and the process completes. [...]
>
> [[The Python Language Reference: the import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache)]